# Different OS - How to read server txt file with client app

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, utf-8

I am writing a test application. It consists of a small desktop app and servlet. The desktop is a client and is to connect to my servlet, as I suppose, from any OS. It is greate but I have a txt file which is on the server. My desktop app adds lines to the txt file (images files names). The lines may contain cyrillic words like a "картинка1.jpg" and that is the most big problem because I cannot get the original cyrillic image name back to my client. That's make impossible to download image by using its name because server cannot identify such an image name like a "???????1.jpg" to read it back to my client.  I know it is all the encoding problem but I am wondering how to make my client desktop app work correctly togather with my servlet which is on linux? I mean what should me do if my client and server have different localization and "file.encoding"?

OK... accepting your silence I want to decrypt some details... So things I do and things I get are

- A) (client) I use JFileChooser to get
  image file name (lets call it nameX)
- B) (client) I use httpclient 4 and
  StringBody(nameX,"utf8") to send the
  nameX to my servlet
- C) (server) Gets nameX from FileItems
  and writes (adds) it to N.txt file
- D) (client) I get the images file
  names list shown (in cp1251 encoding
  because the client supports it) and
  choose the "nameX"
- E) (client) Sends the "nameX" with
  StringBody(nameX,"utf8") header to
  servlet
- F) (server) Gets nameX but for some
  reason it is something like
  ??????1.jpg so it cannot identify the
  file name is...

SO my problem is somewhere is back/previous encoding I guess but I am not sure...

I have checked my server encoding it is

- os.name = Linux
- sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
- file.encoding = UTF-8
- user.language = en

and my client is:

- os.name = Windows XP
- sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1251
- file.encoding = Cp1251
- user.language = ru

Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Comment: Ensure you use UTF-8 in both ends rather than depending on whatever's default in your environment.

Comment: Well, as I get it, my client is windows and it uses cp1251 and the server is unix and it uses utf-8

Comment: But how can I make my servlet write correct images names list into the unix txt file if I copy the images names right from my client OS? I tried to encode all names from cp1251 to utf-8 but for some reason I in fact get the windows encoding only :(

Comment: I test both the client and server with the IO on my windows OS but the text=new String(text.getBytes(),"utf8"); doesn't help because I open the txt file with my IE8 and can see it with windows encoding mode only not the unicode or so...

Comment: So I want to adapt images names to put them down into the server txt file correctly despite any client encoding but I have confused a little... Please help me

Comment: And I don't get it can it help like a "JAVA_OPTS with the value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" for server case? Because I am not pretty sure of the unix licalization settings...

Comment: quote: "Ensure you use UTF-8 in both ends rather than depending on whatever's default in your environment."
Emm its greate but I suppose the client can be installed and get started on any OS (platform independant) so its encoding can be utf-8 or cp1251 etc but the server encoding I think is utf-8 or maybe its licalized version ru_RU.utf-8. I want to keep a client uploaded images - their names in server txt. But I want to download the images back and here is the problem because of a client and server different file.encoding :(

Comment: You're calling new String(text.getBytes(),"utf8"); shouldn't you be calling ...text.getBytes("utf8")... instead ?

Comment: Emm... Is there some difference with the new String(text.getBytes(),"utf8"); and text.getBytes("utf8")?

Comment: Well actually I am doing the encoding like new String(text.getBytes(),"utf8"); for image name which I am going to send to server and then write it to the server txt file... Am I doing something wrong with it?

Comment: Can anyone just tell me why writing string to txt file like text=new String(text.getBytes(),"utf8"); writes txt file with cp1251 encoding?

Comment: and how to encode the image file name to utf8 to write it correctly in ciryllic to server txt file?

Comment: Oh, my ... does anyone tried to keep windows file names in linux txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. When writing to a file: new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(File), "UTF-8"));
2. When retrieving the image file from the web server, do not use anything but ASCII in the URL. Unfortunately, only ASCII will work reliably across all web clients and servers.

Comment: So maybe that is the problem? UTF-8 cannot work everywhere? But what if a local file system file name is Cp1251 cyrillic or something? So how can I keep such kind of files with their original names? Is there some alt way?

Comment: The problem is not with the java environment (client and server). As you know, Java has excellent support for encodings. The problem is with the web clients and web frameworks: they do not support non-ASCII URLs. The problem is with the HTTP specification itself, not the implementations. --- You should develop a simple algorithm to convert between cyrillic names to ascii urls and back. Not an ideal solution but something that will work.

Comment: An alternate solution should be to retrieve the images with HTTP POST as then the cyrillic name will be included in the request body and not the URL itself. Another non-ideal solution but it should at least work.

Comment: Oh, I tried to work around cyrillic file names right with the StringBody itself... The thing was between Linux and Windows so the platforms encoding were different :( But the result still was nothing but "??????"

Comment: I was using the multipart httpcomponent to put the file and its cyrillic name with the StringBody(cyrillicText,encoding) but the result was the same... So my question is still unrecovered as... can JRE modify OS locale within the file gets its name during the OutputStream(ing)? Because cp1251 cannot be shown correctly for Linux UTF-8 :(

Comment: emm... or maybe there is a walk around? Because, as I can get it, cyrillic encoding in cp1251 and UTF-8 doesn't have the same code page indexes range?